# Wake Raspberry using PS3 controller

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, bluetooth, retropie

I have a PS3 controller connected via Bluettoth to my RetroPie and when I leave it for a few minutes it idles. Now I want to wake it up with my controller. 
My first idea was to try bluetooth event handling but I didn't find any useful documentation about this.

Do you have any good ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to RPi.SE. I believe when you say Retropie "idles", does it mean screen goes blank and screensaver activates ? If that is the case, you can associate bluetooth activity with a script or something which deactivates screen saver by using appropriate `xset` command. Tell us what you've tried so far and at what particular step you're facing the problem.

Comment: Yes that's the case. That's exactly what I want. A script that runs when I press e.g. the PS button. Didn't find anything

Comment: If your ps3 controller is paired already, your pi should "wake up" if you touch any key/joystick on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

As @Havnar suggested if the PS3 controller is still connected to the Pi when it idles, as soon as you start pressing buttons on the PS3 controller the Pi will wake up.

I can confirm this is possible as I can wake up a Pi with XBMC installed on it using an app on my phone connected to the Pi using Wi-Fi.